# How to test the children of an element in cypress?

Tags: cypress

If I have these elements

```
<div class="diffed-chunks">
    <div class="diffed-chunk diffed-chunk--pending"></div>
    <div class="diffed-chunk">1</div>
    <div class="diffed-chunk">2</div>
</div>
```

Is there a simpler way of testing it than doing this?

```
cy.get('.diffed-chunks .diffed-chunk').as('diffed-chunks');
cy.get('@diffed-chunks')
  .eq(0)
  .should('have.class', 'diffed-chunk--pending');
cy.get('@diffed-chunks')
  .eq(1)
  .should('have.text', '1');
cy.get('@diffed-chunks')
  .eq(2)
  .should('have.text', '2')
```

Comment: I started to type out an answer, but now that I look harder I see you have want to be able to choose what element at a index has certain class or contains a certain text... Is that correct?

Comment: @Maccurt Yes, I want to be able to see that element X has a specific class and that element Y has a specific text. There might be multiple conditions, so I was wondering if I could do something like `cy.get('@diffed-chunks').should('have.classes', ['diffed-chunk--pending', '', ''])`

Comment: To be honest I can't see a better way of doing, I had never used the the .as() command so I learned something about alias from your post. I wish I could help, but I have no problem with what you are doing. Perhaps someone else will shed more light on it. sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a matter of opinion, but a pattern I like is

- define an expected array
- select all children by attributes that are not being tested
- compare actual array against expected array

```js
const expected = [
  {
    text: '',
    classes: 'diffed-chunk diffed-chunk--pending',
  },
  {
    text: '1',
    classes: 'diffed-chunk',
  },
  {
    text: '2',
    classes: 'diffed-chunk',
  },
];

const getText = el => el.textContent.trim()

it('should have expected text', () => {
  cy.get('.diffed-chunks div').then(els => { 
    const texts = [...els].map(getText)
    expect(texts).to.deep.eq(expected.map(x => x.text))
  })
});

const getClasses = el => el.className

it('should have classes', () => {
  cy.get('.diffed-chunks div').then(els => { 
    const classes = [...els].map(getClasses)
    expect(classes).to.deep.eq(expected.map(x => x.classes))
  })
});
```